# How to define qualify attribute with tablename for Yii2 GridView

Tags: gridview, yii2, relation

I'm using a model with Yii2 GridView which has a relation. That causes an SQL error if I try to search by an ID on the index page, because the ID is unambiguous.

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'id' in
>   where clause is ambiguous The SQL being executed was: SELECT COUNT(*)
>   FROM `re_ingredient` LEFT JOIN `re_ingredient_lang` ON
>   `re_ingredient`.`id` = `re_ingredient_lang`.`ingredient_id` LEFT JOIN
>   `re_ingredient_group_lang` ON `re_ingredient`.`ingredient_group_id` =
>   `re_ingredient_group_lang`.`ingredient_group_id` WHERE ((`id`='1') AND
>   (`re_ingredient_lang`.language='en-US')) AND
>   (`re_ingredient_group_lang`.language='en-US')

My code in `views/ingredient/index.php`:

> ```
> <?= GridView::widget([
>     'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
>     'filterModel' => $searchModel,
>     'columns' => [
>         ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
>
>         ['attribute' => 'id', 'contentOptions' => ['width' => '80px'] ],
>         ['attribute' => 'NDB_No', 'contentOptions' => ['width' => '80px'] ],
>         ['attribute' => 'group_name', 'value' => 'ingredientGroupLang.name'],
>         ['attribute' => 'name', 'value' => 'translation.name'],
>         ['attribute' => 'name_alt', 'value' => 'translation.name_alt'],
>         'name_lat',
>         // 'created_at',
>         // 'updated_at',
>
>         ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn', 
>          'contentOptions' => ['style' => 'white-space: nowrap;'] ],
>     ],
> ]); ?>
> ```
>
> How can I achieve, that `re_ingredient.id` is used in the where clause instead of the simple `id`?

Comment: Add your search model code (the part where `$dataProvider` is formed).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add `re_ingredient.id` instead of `id` in your `public function search()`

```
$query->andFilterWhere(['like', 're_ingredient.id', $this->id]) //here re_ingredient.id
```

that's it.

Comment: Thanks, the solution is trivial and I've overseen it. In my opinion Gii should use tablename everywhere, i.e. thze default Gii templates are not really correct.